# RNCamera - onFaceDetectionError not working in both Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-camera

I am not able to find not detecting the face scenario using RNCamera.

dependencies: 
"react-native": "0.61.5",
"react-native-camera": "git+https://git@github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera.git",

this is how I am using the RNCamera,
....

```
    <RNCamera 
      ref={ref => {this.camera = ref}}
      type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.front}
      onFacesDetected={this.handleFaceDetected}
      onFaceDetectionError = {this.faceDetectionError}
    </RNCamera>
    ...
    handleFaceDetected = (faces) => {
            console.log('face detected!')
        }

    faceDetectionError = (error) => {
            console.log('face Not detected!')
        }
```

I also faced that even though the camera is not in front of any faces, in some of the android devices it is triggering the onFacesDetected method.

Any help in this is much thankful.
Thanks in advance.